# Is it possible to use two select statements with mongo db in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im in a specific situation where I have to select all records in a mongo db collection but also a record with a specific Id. I understand how to get the whole lot of records but how can I query a record with a specific id as well.

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Term.find().sort({ "term": 1 })
    .then(result => {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About page', terms: result });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    const id = req.params.id;
    Term.findById(id)
    .then(results => {
        res.render('about', { specific: results })
    })
});
```

would the above code work as I have queried the whole database with `Term.find` but also `Term.findbyId(id)`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Hard to understand what you need, is it running 2 queries and then returning both results at the same time?

Comment: yes run two queries and then get both results

Comment: Alright, please try with the code I shared, should do what you need :)

Comment: thank you works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need, return both things in the same handler.

```
app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Term.find()
    .sort({ term: 1 })
    .then(result =>
      Term.findById(id).then(results =>
        res.render("about", {
          specific: results,
          title: "About page",
          terms: result
        })
      )
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select all records in first query and load all data from db - you don't need a second query. You can do this with plain javascript with data that already received from first query.

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Term.find().sort({ "term": 1 })
    .then(result => {
       const specific = result.find(item => item._id.toString() === req.params.id);
       res.render('about', {
           specific,
           title: 'About page',
           terms: result
       });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

If you don't load all data. Probably you have some paginations. You can run 2 query concurrently.

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Promise.all([
        Term.find().sort({ "term": 1 }), 
        Term.findById(req.params.id)
    ])
    .then(values => {
        res.render("about", {
          title: "About page",
          terms: values[0],
          specific: values[1]
        })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(err));
});
```